# jquery if div has display none addclass to parent class

Tags: jquery, if-statement, parent

I want to add a class onto the div with class 'catresults' if the divs below it with class 'refinement_category_item' have a style="display:none".

```
 <div class="refinement_category_section">
    <div class="find_by_category_text">
      <div class="catresults">By Category</div>
    </div>
    <div class="refinement_category_item" style="display: none"> <a onclick="Add_Search_Param('cat', '2847'); Refine();" href="javascript: void(0);" class="refinement_category_link"> <span class="refinement_category_text">Back Bar Coolers (61)</span> </a> </div>



   $(document).ready(function(){
  if($(".refinement_category_item").not(":visible")){
  $(".refinement_category_item").parent().find("div.catresults").addClass('backgroundfilter');
  }
});
```

Comment: I'm confused. In your HTML, the `refinement_category_item` doesn't have a parent with `catresults`.

Comment: Perhaps my question was unclear again.  I simply want to add a class onto the div with class 'catresults' if the divs below it with class 'refinement_category_item' have a style="display:none".

Comment: @ToddN: That makes more sense. I [added an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5011183/jquery-if-div-has-display-none-addclass-to-parent-class/5011483#5011483). Only thing that concerns me a little is that you refer to the *divs* (plural) below it. I see only one, so if there are several that must be tested, it will change the solution.

Comment: Yes there are several divs that are identical in class.  When DIV class='catresults' is selected it toggles all the divs below it (display=none), so I want to add a background to it when selected (addclass).

Comment: @ToddN: What do you mean by *catresults is selected*. How does it get selected? Does it get clicked? Is some other code selecting it?

Comment: Yes it gets clicked and I have JQuery code set to toggle it when clicked.  I want to add a class to it so it will have a background color and a different image (arrow to the right) when clicked and all the little results are hidden. [Click Here to see the left navigation filter in action](http://www.basequipment.com/SearchResults.asp?Search=freezer&Search.x=0&Search.y=0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(".refinement_category_item:hidden").prev()
                           .children('.catresults').addClass('backgroundfilter');
```

Answer (score 7):

```
var div = $('.refinement_category_item');

if ( ! div.is(':visible')) {
   div.parent().addClass('backgroundfilter');
}
```

Some notes...

- `this` is set by jQuery - it is not set by an `if` construct.
- Using `is(':visible')` is the jQuery way.
- When adding a class with `addClass()`, you do not not put the leading `.` there.
- It is better generally to use the DOM ready `$(function() { ... })` then putting your scripts inline under the DOM elements.

Answer (score 1):

You use `$(this)` where the code doesn't know what `$(this)` is. You should use `$(".refinement_category_item")` there too.

Also `$(".refinement_category_item").css('display')== 'none'` could also be `$(".refinement_category_item").is(':hidden')`

Comment: I have modified the code, but it is not adding the class to where I need it to be: `<script>
if($('div.refinement_category_item').is(':hidden') ){
$('catresults').addClass('.backgroundfilter');
}
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  if($(".refinement_category_item").is(":visible")){
  $(".refinement_category_item").parent().find("div.catresults").addClass('.backgroundfilter');
  }
});
```

Comment: This kind of worked, however when I change ':visible' to ':hidden" it does not add the class when the div changes to style="display: none"

Comment: There is no such selector as :hidden, :visible means that element is visible (conditions: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

I'd be more inclined to do something like this. Untested code, but the principles are sound.

HTML:

```
<div class="refinement_category_section">
    <div class="find_by_category_text">
      <div class="catresults">By Category</div>
    </div>
    <div class="refinement_category_item"> <a onclick="Add_Search_Param('cat', '2847'); Refine();" href="javascript: void(0);" class="refinement_category_link"> <span class="refinement_category_text">Back Bar Coolers (61)</span> </a> </div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($(".refinement_category_item").not(":visible")) {
        $(this).parent().addClass(".backgroundfilter");
    }
});
</script>
```